# `Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one` when use `%>%`

Tags: r, aggregate

```
library(mirt)
library(psych)
df<-bfi
df<-mutate(df,group=cut(age,c(0,20,40,60,100)))

#workable
aggregate(df[, -which(names(df) %in% c("gender", "education", "age","group"))],by=list(df$group),FUN= mean)

#same function,not workable
df %>% aggregate(.[, -which(names(.) %in% c("gender", "education", "age","group"))],by=list(.$group),FUN= mean)
```

When run above script, you can find `Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one` when use pipe `%>%`to a same function.

What's the problem?

Comment: Why not use `group_by-summarise/mutate` since you're working with `dplyr` or are you just using the `pipe`?

Comment: @NelsonGon, I just want to figure out the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data with `dput`?

Comment: I've failed to download `psych` so cannot use your data to answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data, this is a shot in the dark. I think the issue is to do with `which`, if we `select` first, it makes capturing the data easier. I'm also a fan of the formula notation hence the usage.

```
iris %>%   
   .[-which(names(.)%in% c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))] %>% 
  aggregate(.~Species,.,FUN=mean)
     Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        5.552       2.026
```